# Parse data file in Python

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a pet project, in python, for x-plane but need some help with parsing some data.

This is a sample of the data

```
1      196 1 0 EGKK London Gatwick
100   45.11   1   1 0.00 1 3 0 08R  51.14510986 -000.21231370  392.89    0.00 5  4 1 1 26L  51.15119014 -000.16819230  267.92  182.88 5  4 1 1
100   45.11   1   1 0.00 0 3 1 08L  51.14691084 -000.21256968  320.96    0.00 4  7 0 1 26R  51.15180116 -000.17681432  416.05    0.00 4  7 0 1
21   51.14622685 -000.20070224  3  77.60   3.00 08R PAPI-4R
21   51.14935802 -000.17789218  2 257.60   3.00 26L PAPI-4L
110   2 0.00  77.70 Parking positions 101-103
111  51.15774074 -000.17453421 
111  51.15612096 -000.17392833 
111  51.15658181 -000.17088556 
113  51.15811289 -000.17149989 
111  51.15791243 -000.17250212 
111  51.15761372 -000.17239479 
111  51.15749171 -000.17330039 
113  51.15779042 -000.17341443 
110   1 0.00 167.70 Ramp
111  51.15286332 -000.16377606 
111  51.15258969 -000.16312609 
111  51.15454938 -000.16302507 
113  51.15403028 -000.16372478 
110   2 0.00  77.50 Twy J west
111  51.14804859 -000.21064157  51 102 
111  51.14845633 -000.20754956  51 102 
112  51.14845142 -000.20696022  51.14842303 -000.20680182  51 102 
111  51.14822704 -000.20686650  51 102 
111  51.14787041 -000.20703621 
111  51.14809780 -000.20534823  51 102 
112  51.14835596 -000.20601269  51.14854333 -000.20604889 
111  51.14835596 -000.20601269 
112  51.14835596 -000.20601269  51.14846668 -000.20603079  51 102 
111  51.14853305 -000.20582527  51 102 
111  51.14878419 -000.20507558  51 102 
111  51.14915518 -000.20239537  51 102 
111  51.15028333 -000.19414918  51 102 
112  51.15015284 -000.19308931  51.14990429 -000.19299026  51 102 
111  51.14977192 -000.19312473 
111  51.14994515 -000.19188237  51 102 
112  51.15024605 -000.19228698  51.15042624 -000.19235632  51 102 
111  51.15068101 -000.19129646  51 102 
111  51.15181209 -000.18271022 
111  51.15207776 -000.18279411  51 102 
111  51.15170518 -000.18556349 
111  51.15134334 -000.18819268  51 102 
112  51.15080761 -000.19200036  51.15080249 -000.19202760 
111  51.15080761 -000.19200036 
112  51.15080761 -000.19200036  51.15073926 -000.19263232  51 102 
111  51.15139885 -000.19291562  51 102 
111  51.15299423 -000.19345539  51 102 
112  51.15345927 -000.19346592  51.15352079 -000.19342233 

1       20 1 0 YPAD Adelaide Intl
100   46.02   1   2 0.25 1 3 1 05  -34.95852900  138.51720042  157.89    0.00 5  3 1 1 23  -34.94065900  138.54330673    0.00   61.87 5  3 1 0
100   46.02   1   0 0.25 0 2 1 12  -34.94117850  138.52191000    0.00    0.00 5  3 1 0 30  -34.94939000  138.53698400    0.00    0.00 5  3 1 0
102 H1  -34.93518312  138.53192488 231.46   29.87   29.87   2 0   0 0.00 1
102 H2  -34.94658683  138.52277413 356.62   41.15   39.93   2 0   0 0.00 1
21  -34.94333383  138.54033847  2 230.00   3.00 New PAPI-4L
21  -34.94261483  138.53961547  3 230.00   3.00 New PAPI-4R
21  -34.95335269  138.52397752  2  50.00   3.00 New PAPI-4L
21  -34.94767809  138.53483040  3 303.70   3.00 New PAPI-4R
21  -34.94847005  138.53417115  2 303.70   3.00 New PAPI-4L
21  -34.94320477  138.52444181  3 123.70   3.00 New PAPI-4R
21  -34.94241898  138.52511056  2 123.70   3.00 New PAPI-4L
110   1 1.00 123.70 New Taxiway 199
111 -34.94102671  138.52209460 
111 -34.94093997  138.52194695 
111 -34.94128895  138.52166396 
113 -34.94136359  138.52179930 
110   2 1.00 123.70 New Taxiway 213
111 -34.94720010  138.53242703 
112 -34.94773614  138.53247063 -34.94793107  138.53226849 
111 -34.94814549  138.53282734 
111 -34.94759966  138.53339333 
111 -34.94776762  138.53436555 
112 -34.94716011  138.53434812 -34.94687064  138.53464022 
111 -34.94705647  138.53349360 
113 -34.94707434  138.53308815 
110   4 1.00   0.00 New Taxiway 85
111 -34.93416388  138.53331538 
112 -34.93417175  138.53324032 -34.93417896  138.53319052 
111 -34.93421978  138.53219165 
111 -34.93425647  138.53169827 
112 -34.93427328  138.53165726 -34.93428528  138.53164555 
111 -34.93435973  138.53166019 
111 -34.93474635  138.53169242 
111 -34.93546623  138.53082742 
112 -34.93547218  138.53049092 -34.93548608  138.53048365 
112 -34.93559920  138.53043281 -34.93563294  138.53041587 
111 -34.93572637  138.53040795 
111 -34.93566141  138.53051888
```

Each Row Header that starts with a 1 represents an airport with all subsequent row headers representing different aspects of the airport, e.g.:

```
111 Plain Node
112 Node with Bezier Control Point
113 Node Close Loop to close boundary
114 Node Close Loop with Bezier Control Loop
115 Node to Terminate Line
116 Node with Bezier Control Point
```

So how would I parse this data file, and read/use only the information that is relevant to that particular data block, ie: between the 1's Then drill down further to use the airports data etc.

Comment: There are several ways how to parse text files. Probably, the easiest in your case is to use "csv" module. First try some code, and if you have any problems, ask a more concrete question.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I suggest you do is write some code that allows you to check if you are handling a new airport, but that doesn't consume that line. So that while handling the airport specific codes, you know when the next one starts.

Somewhat more difficult is to make something that allows you to read a line and push it back.

Once you can actually parse the lines and find the new airport, you can use that to create an airport object that knows how to handle the different non-1 codes and fill out its information, based on the actual code.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

from __future__ import print_function

class ParseAirportInfo(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self._fp = open(filename)
        self._line = None

    def check(self):
        if self._line is None:
            self._line = self._fp.readline()
        if self._line == '':
            return -1
        split_line = self._line.split(None, 1)
        if split_line and split_line[0] == '1':
            return 1
        return 0

    def read(self):
        if self._line:
            retval = self._line
            self._line = None
            return retval
        return self._fp.readline()

class Airport(object):
    def __init__(self, line):
        # split the line starting with 1 and process the info
        pass

    def process_line(self, line):
        # split the line and process depending on the first value
        if line == '\n':
            return
        code, rest = line.split(None, 1)
        code = int(code)
        if code == 111:
            pass
        elif code == 110:
            pass

airports = []

def main():
    pai = ParseAirportInfo('airport.txt')
    airport = None
    while not pai.check() == -1:
        if pai.check() == 1:
            airport = Airport(pai.read())
        while pai.check() == 0:
            l = pai.read()
            airport.process_line(l)

main()
```

Comment: @Whitetimer You would not, as there is no need. The OP explicitly mentioned a Python program in text and tag. (However both being OOPL it would structurally make them the same. Give it a try and when you get stuck post a new question on SO and refer to this one if it helps to provide context).